# Using ESXi 4 with more than 1 physical CPUs

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere, host

I found this sort of question has been asked many times, but unfortunately I was unable to find the proper answer for the case I'm describing here.
Well these are the details:

I got from VMware 2 licenses for ESXi 4 Update 1. One ist for up to three Hosts and the other is for up to 10 Hosts. The license registration
procedure does not allow to specify how many physical CPUs should be licensed. So now on my IBM BladeServer with 2x Intel Xeon Dual Core
CPUs the ESXi 4 Server recognizes and uses only one of the CPUs - 1 CPU with 2 Cores. Maximal number of vCPUs is 2. It also says
Licensed for 1 CPU. The license itself, in its Info dialog, claims to have unlimited support for CPUs, but obviously it is not the case.

There is no way through the vSphere Client to change the number of CPUs the server should use.

Now the real question: what ist way to enable more than 1 CPU for ESXi 4? I've read somewhere in the WWW, there're people successfully using
ESXi 4 with more than 1 CPU, but how to do that stills unknown to me...

For your help and information I'd like to thank you in advance.

Kind regards,
S Bogus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, 
in the vSphere Client, try going to Configuration > Licensed Features > Edit and see if you can assign the new license there for the 10 CPU's

If not it's reinstall time. 
And you need to do the install using the 10CPU licence. 
It's the only why I have had it work :(